# Python Imaplib: Get new gmail mails without reconnect

Tags: python, email, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I'm writing a python script that regularly checks for new email matching a certain search. However it never shows new emails without reconnecting.

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(user,passwd)
mail.select("inbox")
while True:
    result, idData = mail.uid('search', query, "ALL")
    processIDs(idData)
    time.sleep(60)
```

The search finds all emails that match my query at login time, but it never finds emails that arrive while it's running. As soon as I stop the script and restart it, all emails instantly show up.

If googled and looked through the imaplib docs, but couldn't find anything useful.

How can I get the new emails to show without reconnecting to the imap server?

Edit: The reason I want to avoid reconnecting is because of gmail rate limits.

Comment: what if you move these 2 lines `mail.login(user,passwd)` `mail.select("inbox")` inside the while loop ? it is not a perfect fix but can give you desired results , or else you can lookup if thislibrary supports streaming data mode ?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal Yes, if I login in every time it works, but that's what I specifically want to avoid because of gmail login rate limits. I don't know much about imap, if by streaming data mode you mean imap IDLE then I don't think so. From what i've read IDLE is a way to get push updates for new emails, but python imaplib doesn't support that.

Comment: try copying only `mail.select("inbox")` this line inside the loop and see if that works ? I am not sure on this but It should work I guess

Comment: @Anmol_uppal That works, thank you very much. I could have sworn I tried that in ipython but apparently I'm an idiot.

Comment: you are welcomed dude, I have posted the solution, any edit by your side is welcomed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this is a kind of hit and trial approach and finally we get a solution, not optimal though, The hack is to reconnect again every time after the script wakes up from the sleep, to fetch the inbox from start, This can be easily done by refreshing the page(like we reload in the normal browser), So it may look like this :

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(user,passwd)
while True:
    mail.select("inbox")
    result, idData = mail.uid('search', query, "ALL")
    processIDs(idData)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 4):

I know you have accepted an answer, but I think a better approach than reconnecting is to issue the [NOOP command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.1.2).

Comment: This is actual answer, no hack.
instead of  mail.select("inbox") do mail.noop()

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `time.sleep(60)` and [use idle() from this version of imaplib](http://janeelix.com/piers/python/imaplib.html) instead. A 29-minute timeout is fine. You may have to use a shorter timeout if you have a broken NAT gateway in front of your network.

The IMAP command IDLE instructs the server to let the client know as soon as anything has changed. So you run IDLE, then when the server says something, you rerun your search. You should be able to react to changes within a second or two that way.

Comment: Sorry, can you show example of code with IDLE. How to use it...?

Comment: Noop is very different. It does not give the server occasion to report on changes when they happen, only when noop is run.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue NOOP command in the while loop or IDLE for update the IMAP session.