# Is there a way to execute a particular function every time the number of my unread emails changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to make a trading program where it executes a buy/sell (alternating every time) every time I receive an email. I am meant to enter in whether currently it is a buy/sell, so that it can execute the opposite as soon as I receive an email. I thought that I had come up with a solution, but after a while it keeps doing the actions twice. Here it is:

```
import email
import imaplib
import time
import pyautogui as p



#0 is sell, 1 is buy
num = 0
last = 0
isopen = 1


def buy():
    (placeholder)
    

def sell():
    (placeholder)
    
   

def close():
    (placeholder)


    
while True:
    obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com','993')
    obj.login('email', 'password')
    obj.select()
    unread = len(obj.search(None, 'UnSeen')[1][0].split())
    if unread != last:
        num = 1 - num
        if num == 1: #buy
            if isopen != 0:
                close()
            buy()
            print('bought')
            isopen = 1
        if num == 0:
            if isopen != 0:
                close()
            print('sold')
            sell()
            isopen = 1
    last = unread    
    obj.logout()
```

Comment: I hope you buy&sell on your paper account only. Regarding the code, it's a busy loop connecting and disconnecting. AFAIK the standard `imaplib` does not support IDLE (an IMAP command), but see here for code polling every N seconds while keeping the connection active: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28192016/5378816, adapt the check.

Comment: try setting num to 0 at the end of the conditional num==1 and vise versa at the end of if num == 0

Comment: @VPfB yeah its a paper account haha. I'll check out the link, thanks

Comment: @SamanthaCruz thanks I'll try that